# How to implement stacks using a structure while scanning from a file

Tags: c, function, stack

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct
{
    int client_id;
    char business_name [30];
    char client_first_name [20];
    char client_last_name [20];
    char address [40];
    float budget;
    float energy_requirements;
    char business_info [300];
}Client;

main()
{
     Client c[20];
     FILE*z;
     void initialise (FILE*,Client []);
     initialise (z,c);
     system ("PAUSE");
}

void initialise(FILE*z,Client c[])
{
     int x,max=20,top=-1;
     if (top==max-1)
     {
         return;
     }
     top++;           
     for (x=0;x<20;x++)//Assigns all places in the structure to -1 and NULL
     {
        c[x].client_id=-1;
        strcpy(c[x].business_name,"NULL");
        strcpy(c[x].client_first_name,"NULL");
        strcpy(c[x].client_last_name,"NULL");
        strcpy(c[x].address,"NULL"); 
        c[x].budget=-1;
        c[x].energy_requirements=-1;
        strcpy(c[x].business_info,"NULL"); 
     } 
     z=fopen ("Novus.txt","r");
     for (x=0;x<20;x++)//Replaces values in structure with data from text file
     {
         fscanf (z,"%d\n %[^\n]\n %[^\n]\n %[^\n]\n %[^\n]\n%f\n%f\n %[^\n]\n\n",&c[x].client_id,c[x].business_name,c[x].client_first_name,c[x].address,&c[x].budget,&c[x].energy_requirements,c[x].business_info);
     }
     fclose (z);
     void menu (FILE*,Client []);
     menu (z,c);
}   

void menu (FILE*z,Client c[])
{
     int choice;
     do{
         printf ("1.Add Client\n2.Change Client Information\n3.Delete Client\n4.Search Client\n5.Calculate Energy Requirements\n6.View Clients\n7.Terminate Program\nChoose an option from above:");
         scanf ("%d",&choice);
       }while (choice<1||choice>7);
     if (choice==1)
     {
         system ("cls");
         void accept (FILE*,Client []);
         accept (z,c);
     }
     if (choice==2)
     {
         system ("cls");
         void change (FILE*,Client []);
         change (z,c);
     }
     if (choice==3)
     {
         system ("cls");
         void destroy (FILE*,Client []);
         destroy (z,c);
     }
     if (choice==4)
     { 
         system ("cls");
         void search (FILE*,Client []);
         search (z,c);
     }
     if (choice==5)
     {
         system ("cls");
         void energy (FILE*,Client []);
         energy (z,c);
     }
     if (choice==6)
     {
         system ("cls");
         void view (FILE*,Client []);
         view (z,c);
     }
     if (choice==7)
     {
         system ("cls");
         void end (FILE*,Client []);
         end (z,c);
     }
}

void accept (FILE*z,Client c[])//Accepts data from the user. 
{
     int max=20,top=-1;
     int y=0,num,choice,choice2;
     if (top==max-1)
     {
          return;
     }
     top++;          
     printf("How Many Clients Do You Want To Add:");
     scanf ("%d",&num);
     system ("cls");
     while (y<num)
     { 
          printf ("\nEnter Client ID:");
          scanf ("%d",&c[y].client_id);
          printf ("Enter Buisness Name:");
          scanf (" %[^\n]",c[y].business_name);
          printf ("Enter Client First Name:");
          scanf (" %[^\n]",c[y].client_first_name);     
          printf ("Enter Client Last Name:");
          scanf (" %[^\n]",c[y].client_last_name);     
          printf ("Enter Buisness Address:");
          scanf (" %[^\n]",c[y].address);
          printf ("Enter Client Budget:");
          scanf ("%f",&c[y].budget);
          printf ("Enter Client Energy Requirements:");
          scanf ("%f",&c[y].energy_requirements);
          printf ("Enter Buisness Information:");
          scanf (" %[^\n]",c[y].business_info);
          y++;
     }
     do {//Asks the user if they want to enter more data or terminate program.
           printf ("\n\nDo You Want To:\n1.EnterMore Clients\n2.Continue\n");
           scanf ("%d",&choice);
        }while (choice<1 || choice>2);
     if (choice==1)
     {
         void accept (Client []);
         accept (c);
     } 
     else if (choice==2)
     {
          do{
               printf ("\n\nDo You Want To:\n1.Go Back To The Main Menu\n2.Exit\n");
               scanf ("%d",&choice2);
            }while (choice2<1 || choice2>2);
            if (choice2==1)
            {
               void menu (Client[]);
               menu (c);   
            }
            else if (choice2==2)
            {
               void end (FILE*,Client []);
               end (z,c);
            }
      }                                            
}
```

I just wanted to find out if I am properly pushing data to the stack, and if I can scan the information from the file to the stack using the method above.

What I wanted to do was design a structure that can be used as a stack, and that can be populated using a pop function, such as that used in the initialise function. What my question is, is that I am fairly new to using stacks, and some times when I try to run my program using stacks, my antivirus program, Kaspersky, detects it as a Trojan Horse. What I wanted to know, is if I am implementing the stack correctly.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What is this statement `void menu (FILE*,Client []);` doing at the end of the `void initialise(FILE*z,Client c[])` function??

Comment: It is obvious that you are far from having finished code. You are often better served passing the address of the array of structs to your function as pointers, but you are not prevented from doing it the way you are. I suspect you will need to clean up your format in `fscanf (z,"%d\n %[^\n]\n %[^\,,,` There are a host of errors that need correcting. When compiling **make sure warnings are enabled** at a minimum use `gcc -Wall -Wextra -o yourproject yourproject.c` (or whatever compiler you use). That will identify areas of concern. I will add a cleaned up version (to extent possible) below.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Just to follow up on bit's comment above: your question as it stands is not suitable for this site.   If you want code review, you should go to codereview.stackexchange.com.  If you have an actual problem (rather than a general question) read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

All errors have been addressed up to the point where you need to define the funcitons called in `menu`, etc... When building, make sure warnings are enabled `gcc -Wall -Wextra -o yourprogram yourprogram.c` at a minimum. In addition to the comment above, I have included comments inline below where attention is first needed. I have also provided the results of the current compile following the code. Finish defining the needed functions and then edit your question above and include any new problems you have run into. Good luck:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    int client_id;
    char business_name[30];
    char client_first_name[20];
    char client_last_name[20];
    char address[40];
    float budget;
    float energy_requirements;
    char business_info[300];
} Client;

int main () {
    Client c[20];
    FILE *z;
    void initialise (FILE *, Client[]);
    initialise (z, c);
    system ("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}

void initialise (FILE * z, Client c[]) {
    int x;
    int max = 20;
    int top = -1;
    if (top == (max - 1)) {
        return;
    }
    top++;
    for (x = 0; x < 20; x++)    //Assigns all places in the structure to -1 and NULL
    {
        c[x].client_id = -1;
        strcpy (c[x].business_name, "NULL");
        strcpy (c[x].client_first_name, "NULL");
        strcpy (c[x].client_last_name, "NULL");
        strcpy (c[x].address, "NULL");
        c[x].budget = -1;
        c[x].energy_requirements = -1;
        strcpy (c[x].business_info, "NULL");
    }
    z = fopen ("Novus.txt", "r");
    for (x = 0; x < 20; x++)    //Replaces values in structure with data from text file
    {
        fscanf (z,
                "%d %[^\n]s %[^\n]s %[^\n]s %f %f %[^\n]s",  /* format may need further help */
                &c[x].client_id, c[x].business_name, c[x].client_first_name,
                c[x].address, &c[x].budget, &c[x].energy_requirements,
                c[x].business_info);
    }
    fclose (z);
    void menu (FILE *, Client[]);  /* must be previously declared/defined  */
    menu (z, c);                   /* you just closed 'z' two line up ??   */
}

void menu (FILE * z, Client c[]) {
    int choice;
    do {
        printf
            ("1.Add Client\n2.Change Client Information\n3.Delete Client\n4.Search Client\n5.Calculate Energy Requirements\n6.View Clients\n7.Terminate Program\nChoose an option from above:");
        scanf ("%d", &choice);
    } while (choice < 1 || choice > 7);
    if (choice == 1) {
        system ("cls");
        void accept (FILE *, Client[]);   /* must be previously declared/defined */
        accept (z, c);
    }
    if (choice == 2) {
        system ("cls");
        void change (FILE *, Client[]);   /* must be previously declared/defined */
        change (z, c);
    }
    if (choice == 3) {
        system ("cls");
        void destroy (FILE *, Client[]);  /* must be previously declared/defined */
        destroy (z, c);
    }
    if (choice == 4) {
        system ("cls");
        void search (FILE *, Client[]);   /* must be previously declared/defined */
        search (z, c);
    }
    if (choice == 5) {
        system ("cls");
        void energy (FILE *, Client[]);   /* must be previously declared/defined */
        energy (z, c);
    }
    if (choice == 6) {
        system ("cls");
        void view (FILE *, Client[]);    /* must be previously declared/defined */
        view (z, c);
    }
    if (choice == 7) {
        system ("cls");
        void end (FILE *, Client[]);     /* must be previously declared/defined */
        end (z, c);
    }
}

void accept (FILE * z, Client c[])  //Accepts data from the user.
{
    int max = 20;
    int top = -1;
    int y = 0, num, choice, choice2;
    if (top == (max - 1)) {
        return;
    }
    top++;
    printf ("How Many Clients Do You Want To Add:");
    scanf ("%d", &num);     /* with multiple uses of scanf, you will need to flush the input buffer to      */
    system ("cls");         /* eliminate remaining '\n' chars that remain after the user presses 'Enter'    */
    while (y < num) {       /* a simple 'int c;... do {c = getchar();} while (c != '\n'); after each scanf  */
        printf ("\nEnter Client ID:");          /* will suffice. (note 'c' is declared as an 'int'          */
        scanf ("%d", &c[y].client_id);
        printf ("Enter Buisness Name:");
        scanf (" %[^\n]", c[y].business_name);
        printf ("Enter Client First Name:");
        scanf (" %[^\n]", c[y].client_first_name);
        printf ("Enter Client Last Name:");
        scanf (" %[^\n]", c[y].client_last_name);
        printf ("Enter Buisness Address:");
        scanf (" %[^\n]", c[y].address);
        printf ("Enter Client Budget:");
        scanf ("%f", &c[y].budget);
        printf ("Enter Client Energy Requirements:");
        scanf ("%f", &c[y].energy_requirements);
        printf ("Enter Buisness Information:");
        scanf (" %[^\n]", c[y].business_info);
        y++;
    }
    do {            //Asks the user if they want to enter more data or terminate program.
        printf ("\n\nDo You Want To:\n1.EnterMore Clients\n2.Continue\n");
        scanf ("%d", &choice);
    } while (choice < 1 || choice > 2);
    if (choice == 1) {
        accept (z, c);
    } else if (choice == 2) {
        do {
            printf
                ("\n\nDo You Want To:\n1.Go Back To The Main Menu\n2.Exit\n");
            scanf ("%d", &choice2);
        } while (choice2 < 1 || choice2 > 2);
        if (choice2 == 1) {
            menu (z, c);
        } else if (choice2 == 2) {
            end (z, c);
        }
    }
}
```

**Current Compiler Errors:**

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -o bin/addrstack addrstack.c

addrstack.c: In function ‘accept’:
addrstack.c:148:17: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘end’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
                end (z, c);
                ^
addrstack.c:97:18: note: previous declaration of ‘end’ was here
            void end (FILE *, Client[]);     /* must be previously declared/defined */
                ^
addrstack.c:148:17: error: incompatible implicit declaration of function ‘end’
                end (z, c);
                ^
addrstack.c:97:18: note: previous implicit declaration of ‘end’ was here
            void end (FILE *, Client[]);     /* must be previously declared/defined */
```

Answer (score -1):

I use the following codes for generic stack for any type.
In the example, I create a stack of `int`. Yet you can typedef your type to a name, and use `DeclareStackType(YourType)` to declare a data structure for the stack, and then use `stack__YourType  foo;`  to declare the stack. See test code for detail.

```
#include <malloc.h>


#define DeclareStackType(ValueType) \
   typedef struct { \
       int size; \
       ValueType *buf; \
       int index; \
   } stack_ ## ValueType

#define InitStack(stack, ValueType, sz) do {stack.size = sz;  stack.buf=(ValueType*)malloc(sizeof(ValueType)*sz); stack.index = 0;} while (0)

// this re-uses the already initialized buffer. Just reset index to zero.
#define ClearStack(stack) do {stack.index = 0;} while(0)

#define PushStack(stack, value)  do {stack.buf[stack.index++] = value; } while(0)

#define PopStack(stack) (stack.buf[--stack.index])

#define IsStackFull(stack) (stack.index == stack.size)

#define IsStackEmpty(stack) (stack.index == 0)

#define PushStackSafe(stack, value) do {if (!IsStackFull(stack)) stack.buf[stack.index++] = value;} while(0)

#define PopStackSafe(stack) (stack.buf[IsStackEmpty(stack)? 0 : (stack.index -= 1)])



// --------  test codes  (in C++, since C++ can compile C program, I am lazy to do C printf...)---------------
#include <iostream>

DeclareStackType(int);
stack_int my_integer_stack;

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    InitStack(my_integer_stack, int, 5);

    if (IsStackEmpty(my_integer_stack)) {
        cout << "1. stack empty now" << endl;
    }

    PushStack(my_integer_stack, 1);
    PushStack(my_integer_stack, 2);
    ClearStack(my_integer_stack);   // clear the above input

    if (IsStackEmpty(my_integer_stack)) {
        cout << "2. stack empty now" << endl;
    }

    PushStack(my_integer_stack, 3);
    PushStack(my_integer_stack, 5);
    PushStack(my_integer_stack, 1);
    PushStack(my_integer_stack, 2);
    PushStackSafe(my_integer_stack, 8);

    if (IsStackFull(my_integer_stack)) {
        cout << "3. stack full now" << endl;
    }

    PushStackSafe(my_integer_stack, 9);   // won't push

    cout << PopStack(my_integer_stack) << endl;
    cout << PopStack(my_integer_stack) << endl;
    cout << PopStack(my_integer_stack) << endl;
    cout << PopStack(my_integer_stack) << endl;
    cout << PopStack(my_integer_stack) << endl;

    if (IsStackEmpty(my_integer_stack)) {
        cout << "4. stack empty now" << endl;
    }

    cout << PopStackSafe(my_integer_stack) << endl;  // pop will not go to index -1, yet it returns buf[0] in the stack
}
```

Comment: The questions asked for C help, now a rewrite in C++.

Comment: No.  The answer itself is in C.  I am just been lazy to write the test code in C++.   Test code is not belong to the answer.  Cut the test codes off. (beginning from `#include <iostream>`

Comment: In fact, if you use `printf` to replace all `cout`'s, and remove `#include <iostream>` and `using namespace std`, the whole thing become a perfect C program, including the answer and the test codes.